# Why should strtok(line, "\n") **not** be used to strip the newline left by fgets()

Tags: c, newline, fgets, strtok

`fgets()` is a safe function to read a line of input, but it stores the *new line* byte `'\n'` read from the file in the array if it fits.

In many if not most cases, this *new line* must be removed before further processing the line contents.

Several simple methods can be used for that, but I have seen a compact and tricky proposal:

```
strtok(line, "\n");    // strip the newline
```

Why is this method incorrect and why does it not always work?

Comment: Closely related: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson: interesting reference. I am specifically targeting the misuse of `strtok()` which I have seen multiple times recently.

Comment: Yes, and which is part of the accepted answer on the question I linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is tricky as the `strtok()` function has side effects on a global hidden state variable. This may affect surrounding code and prove hard to debug.

Furthermore, there is a simple case where `strtok(line, "\n")` will not overwrite the `'\n'` with a null byte: If the line read by `fgets()` is an empty line containing only a single *new line* byte. For this contents, `strtok()` will skip the initial *new line*, searching for a different character, which is not present, and return `NULL` **not** modifying the array. Hence it will not strip the *new line*.

**This is a compelling reason to not use `strtok(line, "\n")` to strip the *new line* byte.**

Of course one can *fix* this issue by writing:

```
   if (*line == '\n')
       *line = '\0';
   else
       strtok(line, "\n");
```

Or cumbersome one-liners:

```
    (void)(*line == '\n' ? (*line = '\0') : (strtok(line, "\n"), 0);
```

```
    if (!strtok(line, "\n")) *line = '\0';
```

```
    (void)(strtok(line, "\n") || (*line = '\0'));
```

But the code is no longer compact and still has other side effects.

Other methods are available:

- using an explicit `for` statement:

  ```
    for (char *p = line; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == '\n')
            *p = '\0';
    }
  ```
- using `strlen()`:

  ```
    size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (len > 1 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
        line[--len] = '\0';
    }
    // len is the length if the stripped line
  ```
- using `strchr()`:

  ```
    char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
    if (p) {
        *p = '\0';
    }
  ```
- using `strcspn()` in a one-liner:

  ```
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any.
  ```

Comment: + it is like programming two days the robotic arm for one screw.

Comment: @0___________: or use a [steam hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creusot_steam_hammer) to drive a nail :)